# Tornar ficheiro python num ficheiro com biblioteca

Tags: python

Tenho um ficheiro python que quero transformar em biblioteca de modo a poder chamá-lo num outro ficheiro através do `import subprocess`, para ficheiros com extensão .c o comando sei que é `cc -o nomeficheiro nomeficheiro.c` mas para fazer isso para python não encontro informação como fazer. O que consegui fazer até agora foi o seguinte:

```
nome do ficheiro com este código é libraryteste

     #biblioteca para chamar ficheiros de outra extensÃ£o
        from subprocess import check_output
        import time
        import sys
        from statistics import mean

        tam=1
        vec=[]

        def Average(lst):
            return mean(lst)

        def criaVetor(value):
            for i in range(tam):
                vec.append(value)
            return vec

        while True:
            sensor_data= check_output(['./raspandmax','-d'], shell=False).decode()# chama o ficheiro raspandmax.c em modo diferencial
            output_value = (sensor_data)# mostra o valor analgico lido
            adc_value = float(output_value)# converte o valor analÃ³gico de string para float
            mean_value = Average(criaVetor(adc_value))
            print("{0:.4f}".format(mean_value))
            time.sleep(5)
```

O ficheiro onde faço a importação do código anterior é o seguinte:

```
o nome do ficheiro deste código é sensor_teste
     import libraryteste
        ##### Data of Magnetic Sensor ######################
```

o problema que estou a ter é que quando mando correr o ficheiro sensor_teste ele mostra logo o valor que está a ler no sensor e se eu tento guardar esse valor numa variável não o faz.

Comment: Qualquer arquivo Python pode ser utilizado como módulo em outro arquivo Python. Ou seja, o `import` deve funcionar desde que o arquivo exista e esteja em um dos diretórios de importação (instalado globalmente no ambiente ou localmente na aplicação).

Comment: consegui importar o ficheiro só que não estou a conseguir guardar o valor numa variável, vou editar a pergunta com o código para se perceber melhor a minha dúvida